# in matlab how to search for cell in cell array?

Tags: matlab, search, find

in matlab ,if i have these two cell arrays .in cell array cluster points  for example in the first column i have point 1 ,3 and 4 . so i want to loop over them to find in hops cell array the index of the row which contain 1 in 1st column and 3 in 2nd column which is index 3, then find the index of the row which contain 1 in 1st column and 4 in 2nd column which is index ,then find the index of the row which contain 3 in 1st column and 3 in 2nd column which is index 14, so i can input anything in hops{index,3}

Comment: could you reorder your question to be more clear

Comment: in cell array cluster points the for example in the first column i have point 1 ,3 and 4 . so i want to loop over them to find in hops cell array the index of the row which contain 1 in 1st column and 3 in 2nd column which is index 3, then find the index of the row which contain 1 in 1st column and 4 in 2nd column which is index ,then find the index of the row which contain 3 in 1st column and 3 in 2nd column which is index 14, so i can input anything in hops{index,3}